# Unable to import lib tiff after installing Anaconda on Mac OS X 10.9.2

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mavericks, anaconda, libtiff

I have developed some software using Python under Windows 7.

I have given it to a colleague to run on a Mac (OS X 10.9.2). I have never used a Mac and am having trouble helping them to get started. I have downloaded and installed [Anaconda 1.9.2](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) on the Mac. According to the continuum documentation, `libtiff` is included, but when I run my python file using the Spyder IDE I get the following error when it tries to import `libtiff`:

> ImportError: No module named libtiff.

Following one of the answers on Stack Ooverflow, I tried:

```
conda install libtiff
```

This runs and returns:

> All requested packages already installed.

However on Windows 7 I can see a libtiff folder under `\python27\lib\site-packages`. On the Mac there is no `libtiff` folder under `/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with libtiff 4.0.10, I'm trying to install 4.0.9 but it's been at it for a while now and still hasn't been able to resolve. See more here:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10553

Answer (score 1):

This question is answered here:

[Installing Python modules with Anaconda or Canopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175349/installing-python-modules-with-anaconda-or-canopy)

If pip install libtiff does not work, you can download the source for PyLibTiff as directed at https://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/source/checkout and run setup.py with whichever interpreter you would like for PyLibTiff to be installed to.

Also, you do not have to have the the C libraries that Anaconda installs installed for PyLibTiff to work if you have libtiff libraries installed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear on this. But what you can do to begin with is to type echo `$PATH` from the terminal and see what paths are set. Unclear on how Anaconda interacts with the system, but a good hunch is that if the library file is not in a path then that would cause this.

Also, looking at this thread on [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/F8Q-8xyvrks) it seems that Anaconda installs it’s own libraries that might need to be symbolically linked into the main `/usr/local/lib` directory. The user Denis Engemann—who made the post—posts this bash script in the last response in the thread:

```
for lib in ~/anaconda/lib/*;
do
  ln -s $lib /usr/local/lib/$(basename $lib);
done
```

I would recommend checking those two directories first before linking to make sure all is as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have checked $PATH and added the ~/anaconda/lib to it. However the problem seems to be that the libtiff python wrapper is missing from the installation. If I try the import after copying libtiff.py from Windows 7 into my working directory, then the import gets a bit further, but the libtiff library cannot be found so I may need to do what you suggest once I have found the libtiff python wrapper. First I would like to establish what is wrong with the anaconda installation. I am reluctant to do too much to my colleague's machine because I know so little about MACs.