# Installing Python modules with Anaconda or Canopy

Tags: python, anaconda, canopy, spyder, libtiff

I have played around with Python a little but never have I had to install my own packages. I am currently trying to write a program that reads in 'tiff' files so I'm trying to install the 'libtiff' package and I'm having a nightmare!

First, I was using the Anaconda distribution and the phrase 'conda install libtiff' which would tell me the install was successful. However then I was never able to find libtiff in the Spyder IDE or ipython console.

Having used Canopy in the past, I uninstalled Anaconda and gave Canopy another shot using 'pip install libtiff', however I receive an error saying it failed with error code 1 and I don't know what this is.

I must be missing something fairly crucial but installing this module is proving almost impossible!

Comment: `However then I was never able to find libtiff in the Spyder IDE or ipython` ... well that is because you forgot to set your `PATH` variable properly. It's not a problem with anaconda.

Comment: Were you using the spyder that comes with Anaconda?

Comment: I was using Spyder that came with Anaconda. I used the Anaconda command prompt to load python and ipython, and both of those were unable to find libtiff

Answer (score 2):

Conda's `libtiff` package is the C library, not the Python library. The easiest way to get it would be to use conda to install the dependencies (like `libtiff`, `numpy`), and then use `pip` to install `libtiff` (`pip install libtiff`).

Comment: I had tried that, however libtiff wouldn't install using PIP! I've abandoned libtiff altogether now as I've found I can do what I want with matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

Using `!` on the **IPython** console within spyder allows you to use `pip`. So, in the example, you could do:

```
In [1]: !pip install libtiff
```

Note, this is also available (though perhaps unreliably) on the Python console for Spyder versions before ~2.3.3.